# Django Python __init__() TypeError 'Default' Tutorial

Tags: python, django, default, keyword, typeerror

I'm going through the Django Tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/

I have an error:

> TypeError: `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'Default'

This occurs when I call:

```
$python manage.py sql polls
```

OR

```
$python manage.py syncdb
```

I'm stuck and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I just started the "Activating models" section of the tutorial and input the installed applications

TrackBack:
[settings.py]

```
'Engine': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
'NAME': '/Users/msmith/Documents/djangoPractice/database.db'

$ python manage.py syncdb

$ python manage.py startapp polls
```

[polls.models.py]

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(Default=0)
```

[settings.py] - Added 'polls' to the bottom of the list

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls',
)
```

$python manage.py sql polls -> Error Occurs

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your models definitions, you have `Default=` instead of `default=`. Check the case.

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    #                           ^ Check the case here
```